# Selecting statistical data from a single table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I wish I could write a certain part of the select query as reference but I am not able to figure out the methodology to approach this problem.
I have a table that has several rows, the important four one are

`ID   -   Arrival_Date    -   Type    -   Total_Letters_Received
1    -   '2014-09-26'    -    A      -   3`

etc etc...

What I am trying to get is:

`Year   -    Type    -  Total_Letters_Received
2014   -    A       -   27
2014   -    B       -   33
2012   -    A       -   21`

i.e. each row to show a year, a type, and sum of total letters received in that year of that particular type.

Now I am confused how to pick up the range of years in the original table and then how to make this select query. Please help in this regard

Comment: This is a `group by` query and is a basic part of the SQL language.

Comment: And you can use the `YEAR()` function to convert the `Arrival_Date` into `Arrival_Year`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `sum()` aggregate function and group by the year part of the date.

If on MySQL use the `year()` function:

```
select 
  year(Arrival_Date) as Year, 
  Type, 
  sum(Total_Letters_Received) as Total_Letters_Received
from 
  your_table 
group by 
  year(Arrival_Date), Type
```

If using SQLite3 use the `strftime()` function:

```
select 
  strftime("%Y", Arrival_Date) as Year, 
  Type, 
  sum(Total_Letters_Received) as Total_Letters_Received
from 
  your_table 
group by 
  strftime("%Y", Arrival_Date), Type
```

In the future you might want to tag your question with just the specific database you're actually using instead of multiple different, unless you need the answer to work on all (and if so it might be a good idea to indicate so in the question to avoid confusion).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the year from the `Arrival_Date` using the `year` function, and you can use `group by` and the `sum` aggregate to return the `Total_Letters_Received` per `Year` and `Type`:

```
select
    year(Arrival_Date) as [Year],
    Type,
    sum(Total_Letters_Received) as Total_Letters_Received
from YourTableName
group by
    year(Arrival_Date),
    Type
```